# jQuery if specific tabindex selected

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add class if user jumps in to specific tabindex? I want add class when user tab reaches at specific index and remove class when jumps into another? Thanks!

here i want to add active class when tab focuses at tabindex=3:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
<a href="#" tabindex="3" />Hello</a>
<input type="text" tabindex="4" />
```

here is fiddle for test: http://jsfiddle.net/4XbN3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target the element with the correct tabindex, and add a class on focus :

```
$('[tabindex="3"]').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qZhaW/)

If you need to remove the class, it would be the same thing on blur:

```
$('[tabindex="3"]').on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```